# Log4j is not finding configuration in properties file

Tags: java, servlets, log4j

My log4j.properties file is:

```
# Log levels
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,file
# Appender Configuration
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Path and file name to store the log file
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/Logging/log4jFile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=200KB
# Number of backup files
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
# Layout for Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
```

and the location of log4j.properties file is in WEB-INF of my project.
So when I run my servlet I get this below message:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (...).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Where I am going wrong, I don't understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure by default Log4J searches in the classes directory. So try putting your log4j.properties there.

This is due to log4j searching the classpath for the log4j.properties and the WEB-INF Folder is not part of that but the classes directory is. So either put the file in classes directory, add the file to the classpath or manually load in your Servlet with:

Comment: I placed properties file at that location as well, but same happening! And do you know where does Log4j search for properties file by default!

Comment: and is this line correct in my properties file, I guess nothing is wrong with it,
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/Logging/log4jFile.log

Comment: Your configuration is fine. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You could try to load the file manually just to make sure that's the problem. `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:/Logging/log4j.properties");`

Comment: I found the problem, silly me, I had to locate properties file in src folder but I was locating it at the place where my servlet was placed. Thanks and now its all working. By the way how can it work if I want to place properties somewhere else!

Comment: You can either load it manually in the code like shown in my comment above or pass the following option to the JVM: `-Dlog4j.configuration=mylog4j.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Below is my log4j properties file which works for me. It needs to be in the src/main/resources source folder. I notice the top line is different between mine and yours so maybe this is incorrect - try changing rootLogger to rootCategory.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, FILE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.logger.com.myCompany.log4jexample= TRACE, FILE, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=Logs.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c- %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I figured the problem out. Properties file was not at the default location!